# How to show only 2 out of 3 labels in the legend of geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following dataset, which I would like to plot using `ggplot2` on `R`.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Q = 1:5, R = runif(5), type = c("No Label","Label 1","Label 2","No Label","No Label"))
```

I would like to plot it using the following code

```
ggplot(dat, aes(fill=type, Q, R)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +                   
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.1) +     
    labs(x = "Bin", y =   "R" ) +
    theme_bw() +
    ylim(0,1)+
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "bottom",
          axis.text=element_text(size=28),
          axis.title=element_text(size=28),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 28),
          legend.spacing.x = unit(1.0, 'cm'))
```

but I would like to show in the legend only the labels for data in groups `Label 1` and `Label2`. I couldn't find a way to do that. Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `breaks` in your `scale_fill_grey()` statement in that way you can define the desired labels:

```
#Code
ggplot(dat, aes(fill=type, Q, R)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +                   
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.1,breaks=c('Label 1','Label 2')) +     
  labs(x = "Bin", y =   "R" ) +
  theme_bw() +
  ylim(0,1)+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text=element_text(size=28),
        axis.title=element_text(size=28),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 28),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(1.0, 'cm'))
```

Output:

[image]